# Hiding an Active Choice parameter that outputs HTML

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Im having a **Active Choice Reactive Parameter** , calling it random_number that return an integer.

Assuming i have this code in my groovy script:

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

try{
      foo = 2
      return foo * foo

 } catch(e) {
  return e.message.tokenize()
}
```

The value will be referenced to an **Active Choice Reference Reactive Parameter**, that its going to output in the parameters page an **Formatted HTML**.

Im looking for a way to make my **random_number** hidden as i dont want it to be displayed in the parameters page, but i want it to be used in my Formatted HTML number.

Now, i saw the Hidden Parameter option in the job's configure page. But unfortunately you cant type in groovy script there.

Is there a way to make a parameter that is both **Active Choice** and also **Hidden** ?

[image: This is my Active Choices Reactive Parameter configuration]

[image: This is my HTML Active Choice Reference Reactive Parameter configuration]

[image: And finally this is my output of the parameterized job. My goal is to hide the Choiced parameter above]

I thought about combining the code of both parameters to one parameter that outputs HTML but i want to prevent that as i want to minimize the code amount in each param.

Comment: Want to do also this. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately did not found